# How to solve difference between Browser Resolution and Screen Resolution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, responsive-design

Scenerio : I have to develop a responsive website in Angular JS in which some componets are sized with CSS media query while others with Javascript/Angular.

The problem of difference between Screen and Browser Resolution Starts with devices having width 1600 and above. Actually some browser are having resolution less than the screen resolution while others are exactly same as screen resolution

I am on a Win 10 computer with 14inch Screen and having supported screen resolutions upto 2560x1440

I tried to find out the browser width for some standard resolutions and found the following result:

for Screens 1366x768  Browser Viewport Width : 1366px

for Screens with 1600x900 Browser Viewport Width : 1583px

for Screen with 1920x1080 Browser Viewport Width: 1519.2px

for Screen with 2560x1440  browswer Viewport width 1433px

Now the problem is that css and js both apply the element sizes according to Screen Size and not the browser size, which browser is unable to display properly because it has lower resolution than screen.

Please note : the problem of low resolution on browser is specific to some devices and not all having resolution and all. And this is same for all browser on that device. i.e chrome, mozilla, ie etc.

Edit :

And also i don't want to use Bootstrap and possibly Jquery. If possible please suggest an Angular JS /HTML/CSS approach.

Comment: I've never heard of something like that, can't wait to see why this happens..?? Especially weird is the fact that the viewport width gets smaller and smaller for resolutions superior to 1600x900.. :o

Comment: How how deal with the difference is very simple: Stop caring about the screen size. Care only about the viewport size. *Now the problem is that css and js both apply the element sizes according to Screen Size* — Change your CSS and JS so that is no longer the case.

Comment: @Quentin I also thought to do the same thing. but i am unable to force css or js to use browser size instead of screen size

Comment: @SushilKumarSingh — We can't tell what you are doing wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: @Quentin i have edited my Question to provide the link

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] instead.